# References for magnetic Sobolev spaces

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, quantum-mechanics, potential-theory, electromagnetism

I am working on PDE. Recently I have been studying magnetic Sobolev spaces. While the theory is clear to me, having very little knowledge about physics, I have almost no idea how these spaces help while dealing with some physics problem.

More precisely, I want to know some situations when the operator $\nabla +iA$ comes into picture in physics. Can you suggest some books/notes where these things are explained using very less physics? I mean, it would be great if the intended readers of those notes/book are students of mathematics and not of physics.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When doing QM you frequently deal with the momentum operator, which (if you include field momentum) is $\hat{p}=-i\nabla + \vec{A}$. So a momentum eigenstate, in that context, would be a solution to $\hat{p}\psi=-i\nabla \psi +\vec{A}\psi=\lambda \psi$. More often, one is interested in eigenfunctions of some Hamiltonian operator of the form $\hat{H}=\hat{p}^2/(2m)+V(\vec{x})$ for some scalar potential $V(\vec{x})$. See for instance the Aharanov-Bohm effect, where the choice of boundary conditions makes a big difference (e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.2906).

Comment: Look at lecture 9 of these notes to get some sort of an idea of Sobolev spaces being used in Physics. https://mathswithphysics.blogspot.com/2016/07/frederic-schullers-lectures-on-quantum.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers @Dk65.

Comment: Thank you @Semiclassical.